# Div vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I went through many questions regarding this and also [this](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/) article. I want to center the inside div in the top div element. The only way that I was able to succeed was to make the top div display as table-cell, but when I do that the top div will no longer be a block and doesn't take the complete width of the screen.

Other than using the margin, is there any other way that I can center this inside div.

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="inside">
        <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
</div>



.top{
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    width:auto;
}

.inside{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.inside input{
    display:block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8X4Ps/)

Comment: Could you keep `div.top` as `display: table-cell` and put it in a container `div` with `display: block`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this alternative:

```
.top:before {
  content:" ";
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/8X4Ps/3/**

---

*How this work?*

With the pseudo-selector [:before](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) you are able to generate content elements and handle each property like he was any other tags.

In this case as we have an element with `display:inline-block` then why not center it vertically with property `vertical-align`?

We have a little problem here because this only works in relation with other `inline` elements. And here is where `:before` can help us, what we need is an inline element that takes the `100% height` of the container and then we can align to the middle based on that element.

Comment: yes nice! :)   but does he want to align only vertical or horizontal too?

Comment: @AronMartin the title is *Div vertical alignment* so i guess just vertical, if he wants horizontal is much easier to find in this case just `text-align:center` on .top

Comment: This works. Can you please explain how is this working on a pseudo element ??

Comment: @Srikan now you can check the edit with a little explanation about that

Comment: @Danko. Thank you for the wonderful tip. Sorry for asking so many questions, but I need to understand this. :before and :after psuedo elements where always, a kind of an unexplored territory for me. I have one more question ?. Why do we need to set the vertical-align for the :before element. http://jsfiddle.net/8X4Ps/10/ please check this fiddle. I just added an # to the content of the before element and the vertical-align:middle has not effect on this content. Is this how it is supposed to behave. The vertical align middle will always work on the second element that is inline.

Comment: @Srikan Np mate glad to help you understand, in the case of the VA middle you need to review the property, for inline-block elements just impliy the alignment of the container itself in relation to other inline elements based on his height not aligning inside content, since the :before element is 100% height you can see any difference. For VA inside content is like in tables an `td` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Set the .top to `display:table` give it a width of `width:100%`and set the .inside to `display:table-cell`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abmenzel/8X4Ps/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use padding?

```
.inside
{
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
width:100%;
padding-top:1em;
padding-left:25%;
padding-bottom:1em;
padding-right:25%;
}

.inside input{
display:block;
width:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aronez/8X4Ps/8/

It's working

greets

Comment: Usually you don't use `padding` or `margin` to align because that doesn't support dynamic heights or widths. In this case maybe is possible because he has a fixed height on the .top container but if he wants to modify that he has to change also those values.

Comment: true! but in my fiddle i used     .top { height:auto; }   in that case the padding creates the height of the .top div :)